# iOS - Lazy Symbol Binding Failed

Tags: ios

I have this error occurring on my iOS 5.1 devices/simulator. On iOS 5.0 and 6.0 it's not happening. It happens after this line:

```
[(MyAppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate callFullScreenView:viewController.view];
```

For some reason, it can't reach to callFullScreenView and fires this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/86A386A7-C779-4E3C-9FA2-894B33D22806/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/86A386A7-C779-4E3C-9FA2-894B33D22806/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Any ideas?

Regards!

Comment: Answer suitable for acceptance?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error more than a few times....If you are facing this error set your deployment target to 4.3. By default it is to 6 the latest version.

FYI: This is a repeat of:

[ARC is working in iOS 6 but not work in iOS5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657770/arc-is-working-in-ios-6-but-not-work-in-ios5-1)

Comment: It's a shame this wasn't accepted. It certainly worked for me! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a reminder that if you have multiple projects in a workspace you should check all subprojects.